Polynomial inverse in polynomial module
Given a polynomial $f(z)=\prod(z-\lambda_i)^{v_i},v_i>0$, with the $\lambda_i$ distinct.
$p(z)\in\mathbb F[z]$,if $\lambda_i\neq \lambda_j$ implies $p(\lambda_i)\neq p(\lambda_j)$, and $p^\prime(\lambda_i)\neq 0$ whenever $ν_i>1$.
How to find a $q(z)\in\mathbb F[z]$ s.t. $q(p(z))=z\mod f(z)$  ?
This question is derived from following statement:
A linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $\mathcal V$ is called cyclic if and only if there exists a vector $u\in\mathcal V$ such that $\{A^ku\}_{k=0}^{\dim\mathcal V-1}$ is a basis of $\mathcal V$.
Assume the minimal polynomial of a cyclic operator $T$ factors into linear factors, i.e., $m_T(z)=\Pi\left(z-\lambda_i\right)^{v_i}$ with the $\lambda_i$ distinct. $p(T)$ is cyclic if and only if $\lambda_i \neq \lambda_j$ implies $p\left(\lambda_i\right) \neq p\left(\lambda_j\right)$ and $p^{\prime}\left(\lambda_i\right) \neq 0$ whenever $v_i>1$.
Using Jordan form,I know it’s right. And under the same conditions,that $p(T)$ is cyclic is equivalent to existing a polynomial $q(z) \in \mathbb{F}[z]$ such that $(q \circ p)(z)=z \bmod \left(m_T\right)$.
But I just want to prove it by polynomial approach.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.
